# VB DataGridView Update

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

i have added a DataGridView to a form and made it display in col 1 with the code below.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class editbusinesstype
Dim MyDb As New TillRoll.Group_Business_Type

Private Sub editbusinesstype_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim MyDb As New TillRollDataDataContext(MyConnStr)
    Dim BusinessType = MyDb.Group_Business_Types
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BusinessType
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
End Sub
End Class
```

My Question is when it loads in the grid and i edit a field is there a way i can save it to the database after close.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Other than posting a bunch of irrelevant code, you did not tell us how you are getting the data.  I can't tell from the code what `TillRollDataDataContext` is.

Comment: Hi TillrollDataData actually does do anything ;) i should have removed that. it pulls a view called group_business_type in a database called tillroll, then its display the first col which is called BUSINESSTYPE

Comment: can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to answer the question,  what is `TillRollDataDataContext`?  You say it isn't important and it should have been removed but it tells us how you are working with your data so we can formulate and answer that is relative to you. Are you using MVVM, EntityFramework, Ideablade, DevExpress XPO, DataAdatpters, your own interanal framework, Etc?